# How to send right velocity to model in gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, transmission

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am sending velocity command to gazebo model but it only reflects 35% of commanded velocity. I tried to tune PID gain in config file but it doesn't affect anything. In xacro file also, changing mechanical reduction doesn't seem to work. Does anybody have idea how to fix it so that I can get the velocity what I am commanding to the model?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226821/how-to-send-right-velocity-to-model-in-gazebo?/) by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) on 2016-02-16**:
Please give us more information on what node are you using. If you use a ros controller maybe the config from cmd_vel to hardware is wrong. If you use directly a gazebo controller maybe their is a transmission gearing down the speed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using latter approach. I can say that transmission is the culprit. But changing the mechanicalReduction is not doing anything.

---

Originally posted by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) with karma: 234 on 2016-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0